# change color when class have changed to 'open'

Tags: javascript, html, css

I made a hamburger menu with a class of `.hamburger` (inside `.hamburger`, there is a three `.line` classes)

[shown hamburger menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ODdZy.png)

When I click a hamburger menu, class `.nav-links` pops up and class name changes to `.nav-links .open` when I inspect.

My problem is that opened `.nav-links` color is same as a color I gave to the hamburger menu.

[but it disappears as they both have a same color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1WHm.png)

So I tried to change a hamburger menu(with a class .line) color when class `.nav-links` change to `.nav-links .open` but fail to figure out the solution.

```js
const hamburger = document.querySelector(".hamburger");
const navlinks = document.querySelector(".nav-links");
const links = document.querySelectorAll(".nav-links li");

hamburger.addEventListener('click', () => {
  navlinks.classList.toggle("open");
  links.forEach(link => {
    link.classList.toggle('fade');
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body,
button {
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  width: 90%;
  height: 10vh;
  align-items: center;
  margin: auto;
}

.logo-container,
.nav-links,
.cart {
  display: flex;
}

.logo-container {
  flex: 1;
}

.logo-container img {
  width: 23px;
}

.logo {
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin: 5px;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

nav {
  flex: 2;
}

.nav-links {
  justify-content: space-around;
  list-style: none;
}

.nav-link {
  color: #5f5f79;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.cart {
  flex: 1;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.cart img {
  width: 23px;
}

.presentation {
  display: flex;
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
  margin-bottom: -80px;
  min-height: 80vh;
  align-items: center;
}

.introduction {
  flex: 1;
}

.intro-text h1 {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 500;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #494964, #6f6f89);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

.intro-text p {
  margin-top: 5px;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #585772;
}

.cta {
  padding: 50px 0px 0px 0px;
}

.cta-select {
  border: 1px solid #585772;
  background: transparent;
  color: #585772;
  width: 110px;
  height: 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.cta-add {
  background: #585772;
  width: 110px;
  height: 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 12px;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  margin: 20px 0px 0px 20px;
}

.cover {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 60vh;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: -1;
}

.cover img {
  height: 70%;
  filter: drop-shadow(0px 5px 3px black);
  animation: drop 1.5s ease;
}

.big-circle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: 0.5;
  height: 60%;
}

.medium-circle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30%;
  right: 30%;
  z-index: -1;
  height: 40%;
  opacity: 0.4;
}

.small-circle {
  position: absolute;
  height: 40%;
  bottom: 0%;
  right: 20%;
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: 0.4;
}

.laptop-select {
  width: 15%;
  height: 8px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  position: absolute;
  right: 20%;
}

@keyframes drop {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(-80px);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
  .line {
    width: 15px;
    height: 1px;
    border-radius: 15%;
    background-color: #585772;
    margin: 4px;
  }

  nav {
    position: relative;
  }

  .hamburger {
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    right: -38%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-38%, -50%);
    z-index: 1;
  }

  .nav-links {
    position: fixed;
    background-color: #585772;
    top: 0%;
    bottom: 0%;
    left: 0%;
    right: 0%;
    z-index: 0;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    clip-path: circle(100px at 100% -20%);
    -webkit-clip-path: circle(100px at 100% -20%);
    transition: all 1s ease-out;
    pointer-events: none;
  }

  .nav-links.open {
    clip-path: circle(1500px at 100% -20%);
    -webkit-clip-path: circle(1500px at 100% -20%);
    pointer-events: all;
  }

  .nav-link {
    color: white;
  }

  .nav-links li {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  .nav-links li a {
    font-size: 25px;
  }

  .nav-links li:nth-child(1) {
    transition: all 0.5s ease 0.2s;
  }

  .nav-links li:nth-child(2) {
    transition: all 0.5s ease 0.3s;
  }

  .nav-links li:nth-child(3) {
    transition: all 0.5s ease 0.4s;
  }

  li.fade {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  .presentation {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .introduction {
    margin-top: 5vh;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .intro-text h1 {
    font-size: 30px;
  }
  .intro-text p {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
  .cta {
    padding: 10px 0px 0px 0px;
  }
  .laptop-select {
    bottom: 5%;
    right: 50%;
    width: 50%;
    transform: translate(50%, 5%);
  }
  .cover img {
    height: 80%;
  }
  .small-circle,
  .medium-circle,
  .big-circle {
    opacity: 0.2;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Landing Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body> 
    <header>
        <div class="logo-container">
            <img src="./img/logo.svg" alt="logo" />
            <h4 class="logo">Three Dots</h4>
        </div>
        <nav>
            <div class="hamburger">
                <div class="line"></div>
                <div class="line"></div>
                <div class="line"></div>
            </div>
            <ul class="nav-links">
                <li><a class="nav-link" href="#">Specs</a></li>
                <li><a class="nav-link" href="#">Products</a></li>
                <li><a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>

        </nav>
        <div class="cart">
            <img src="./img/cart.svg" alt="cart" />
        </div>
    </header>
    <main>
        <section class="presentation">
            <div class="introduction">
                <div class="intro-text">
                    <h1>Laptop fot the future</h1>
                    <p>the new 14 inch bezeless display oferring a 4k display with touch screen.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="cta">
                    <button class="cta-select">14 Inch</button>
                    <button class="cta-add">Add To Cart</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="cover">
                <img src="./img/matebook.png" alt="matebook" />
            </div>
        </section>
        <div class="laptop-select">
            <img src="./img/arrow-left.svg" alt="">
            <img src="./img/dot.svg" alt="">
            <img src="./img/dot-full.svg" alt="">
            <img src="./img/dot-full.svg" alt="">
            <img src="./img/arrow-right.svg" alt="">
        </div>
        <img class="big-circle" src="./img/big-eclipse.svg" alt="" />
        <img class="medium-circle" src="./img/mid-eclipse.svg" alt="" />
        <img class="small-circle" src="./img/small-eclipse.svg" alt="" />
    </main>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: I ran your snippet, the links appear fine to me, they're white.

Comment: hello thanks for the answer :) I inserted only part of the code and this happened. I have updated the snippet code to full version. Can you make any suggestions to this?

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, try this out.

What I did was get all the line elements, toggled open on them, for which I added a .line.open bit in the CSS which paints them white.

```js
const hamburger = document.querySelector(".hamburger");
const navlinks = document.querySelector(".nav-links");
const links = document.querySelectorAll(".nav-links li");
const hamLines = document.querySelectorAll(".line");

hamburger.addEventListener('click', () => {
  navlinks.classList.toggle("open");
  links.forEach(link => {
    link.classList.toggle('fade');
  });
  hamLines.forEach(link => {
    link.classList.toggle('open');
  });  
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body,
button {
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  width: 90%;
  height: 10vh;
  align-items: center;
  margin: auto;
}

.logo-container,
.nav-links,
.cart {
  display: flex;
}

.logo-container {
  flex: 1;
}

.logo-container img {
  width: 23px;
}

.logo {
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin: 5px;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

nav {
  flex: 2;
}

.nav-links {
  justify-content: space-around;
  list-style: none;
}

.nav-link {
  color: #5f5f79;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.cart {
  flex: 1;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.cart img {
  width: 23px;
}

.presentation {
  display: flex;
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
  margin-bottom: -80px;
  min-height: 80vh;
  align-items: center;
}

.introduction {
  flex: 1;
}

.intro-text h1 {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 500;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #494964, #6f6f89);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

.intro-text p {
  margin-top: 5px;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #585772;
}

.cta {
  padding: 50px 0px 0px 0px;
}

.cta-select {
  border: 1px solid #585772;
  background: transparent;
  color: #585772;
  width: 110px;
  height: 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.cta-add {
  background: #585772;
  width: 110px;
  height: 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 12px;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  margin: 20px 0px 0px 20px;
}

.cover {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 60vh;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: -1;
}

.cover img {
  height: 70%;
  filter: drop-shadow(0px 5px 3px black);
  animation: drop 1.5s ease;
}

.big-circle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: 0.5;
  height: 60%;
}

.medium-circle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30%;
  right: 30%;
  z-index: -1;
  height: 40%;
  opacity: 0.4;
}

.small-circle {
  position: absolute;
  height: 40%;
  bottom: 0%;
  right: 20%;
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: 0.4;
}

.laptop-select {
  width: 15%;
  height: 8px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  position: absolute;
  right: 20%;
}

@keyframes drop {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(-80px);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
  .line {
    width: 15px;
    height: 1px;
    border-radius: 15%;
    background-color: #585772;
    margin: 4px;
  }
  
  .line.open {
    background-color: white;
  }

  nav {
    position: relative;
  }

  .hamburger {
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    right: -38%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-38%, -50%);
    z-index: 1;
  }

  .nav-links {
    position: fixed;
    background-color: #585772;
    top: 0%;
    bottom: 0%;
    left: 0%;
    right: 0%;
    z-index: 0;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    clip-path: circle(100px at 100% -20%);
    -webkit-clip-path: circle(100px at 100% -20%);
    transition: all 1s ease-out;
    pointer-events: none;
  }

  .nav-links.open {
    clip-path: circle(1500px at 100% -20%);
    -webkit-clip-path: circle(1500px at 100% -20%);
    pointer-events: all;
  }

  .nav-link {
    color: white;
  }

  .nav-links li {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  .nav-links li a {
    font-size: 25px;
  }

  .nav-links li:nth-child(1) {
    transition: all 0.5s ease 0.2s;
  }

  .nav-links li:nth-child(2) {
    transition: all 0.5s ease 0.3s;
  }

  .nav-links li:nth-child(3) {
    transition: all 0.5s ease 0.4s;
  }

  li.fade {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  .presentation {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .introduction {
    margin-top: 5vh;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .intro-text h1 {
    font-size: 30px;
  }
  .intro-text p {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
  .cta {
    padding: 10px 0px 0px 0px;
  }
  .laptop-select {
    bottom: 5%;
    right: 50%;
    width: 50%;
    transform: translate(50%, 5%);
  }
  .cover img {
    height: 80%;
  }
  .small-circle,
  .medium-circle,
  .big-circle {
    opacity: 0.2;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Landing Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body> 
    <header>
        <div class="logo-container">
            <img src="./img/logo.svg" alt="logo" />
            <h4 class="logo">Three Dots</h4>
        </div>
        <nav>
            <div class="hamburger">
                <div class="line"></div>
                <div class="line"></div>
                <div class="line"></div>
            </div>
            <ul class="nav-links">
                <li><a class="nav-link" href="#">Specs</a></li>
                <li><a class="nav-link" href="#">Products</a></li>
                <li><a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>

        </nav>
        <div class="cart">
            <img src="./img/cart.svg" alt="cart" />
        </div>
    </header>
    <main>
        <section class="presentation">
            <div class="introduction">
                <div class="intro-text">
                    <h1>Laptop fot the future</h1>
                    <p>the new 14 inch bezeless display oferring a 4k display with touch screen.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="cta">
                    <button class="cta-select">14 Inch</button>
                    <button class="cta-add">Add To Cart</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="cover">
                <img src="./img/matebook.png" alt="matebook" />
            </div>
        </section>
        <div class="laptop-select">
            <img src="./img/arrow-left.svg" alt="">
            <img src="./img/dot.svg" alt="">
            <img src="./img/dot-full.svg" alt="">
            <img src="./img/dot-full.svg" alt="">
            <img src="./img/arrow-right.svg" alt="">
        </div>
        <img class="big-circle" src="./img/big-eclipse.svg" alt="" />
        <img class="medium-circle" src="./img/mid-eclipse.svg" alt="" />
        <img class="small-circle" src="./img/small-eclipse.svg" alt="" />
    </main>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: On your `.line.open` you shouldn't have to repeat the `width`, `height` etc properties, they will be the same in `.line.open` as they are in `.line` — you should only need the _differences_, which is only the `background-color`. Repeating the unchanged attributes creates a maintenance nightmare, e.g. if you're changing the width from 15px to 20px now you have to make sure you change it in multiple places.

Comment: @StephenP, I updated my answer with your suggestion, thanks.